# How to use ember-cli with custom server and deploy it to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm thinking about rewriting my Ember app using ember cli. The main issue is that I've got a simple custom server (https://github.com/cowbell/sharedrop/blob/master/app/server.js) and I'm not sure what's the best way to handle it.

Should I use http-mocks to setup the server (e.g. enable trusted proxies or add Persona authentication middleware etc.) and all routes? The name "http-mocks" suggests that it's something that should be rather used only in development, not as a real API server.

Maybe I can simply use the server I already got and deploy it together with production version of my app generated by `ember build`?

What's the best way to deploy such apps to Heroku? In the first case it would probably be enough to push the whole repo and run `ember server`. However, what's the best way to deploy it in the second case? I guess I'd only need to push contents of generated `dist` folder together with `server.js` file and then run `node server.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ember-cli exists only as a development harness, once you are ready to deploy it builds you a set of static assets any app server can host. Additionally you can take those assets put them on a CDN and take the index.html and host it from your app server.

```
ember build --env production
```

produces static assets your app server can host.

```
dist/index.html // <- this should live at the root url of your app
dist/assets/*   // <- all your assets finger printed, these can live alongside your index.html or on a CDN (the host is configurable)
```

The http-mocks exist to fake out parts of your backend that do not yet exist.

The proxy is meant to allow you to connect to a backend during development without needing CORs.

All this exists to de-couple your front-end from your backend as both really have different life-cycles and an excellent interface that exists between. (HTTP)